# Moving rows to completey other spreadsheet - convert date to string

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Need some fresh eyes on this if anyone can help. Here is the end goal
Spreadsheet Production with sheet named MASTER
Spreadhsheet Archive_Production with sheet named ARCHMASTER
Need to use string for date formatting of "Tues, Nov 25", so need to convert to string somehow.
My goal is that if MASTER column O has string of "100%" in it AND Column B has a date that is XXX number of days older than today's date then MOVE that entire row to ARCHMASTER.
I already know, at least in my implementation of it, that I can't get the code below to work. This is also not using a conversion to string for dates. I am aware this may create a lot of overhead to do so, but for user's readablity, it is important to use the date format mentioned above. Can anyone help? I am script illiterate, to say the least, as you can tell

```
function onOpen() {

// Next4 lines were suggested in another post.
//var production_sheet_id = '1goG0TS1_2jwlGRetREYNRVk-Q6TEy3iWG_5VXFoZlus';  // This is my source sheet
//var archived_sheet_id = '1Mr4LJmp1SmpDs1i8U_PE5uLOEVjLc599Vq87m9HwCx0';   // This is my destination sheet
// var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(production_sheet_id).getSheets()[0];
//var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(archived_sheet_id).getSheets()[0];
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1goG0TS1_2jwlGRetREYNRVk-Q6TEy3iWG_5VXFoZlus')
   .getSheetByName('MASTER');
  var Sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Mr4LJmp1SmpDs1i8U_PE5uLOEVjLc599Vq87m9HwCx0')
   .getSheetByName('ARCHMASTER');


var rows = sheet1.getDataRange();
var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
var values = rows.getValues();

for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
var oldDate = values[i][1];
var curDate = new Date();

// Count time difference in milliseconds, convert them into days then.
var diffInMilliSecs = (curDate.getTime() - oldDate.getTime());
var diffInDays = diffInMilliSecs/1000/60/60/24;
var diffInDays = Math.round(diffInDays);

if(values[i][14] == 1.0 && Math.abs(diffInDays+30) >= 7)  // It evaluates 100% to 1.0
  sheet2.appendRow(values[i]);
```

}
}

Comment: Specifically which part of the code isn't working for you? I have a number of suggestions to improve this code, but don't want to confuse things by suggesting fixes that have nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: Cameron, you can change anything at all. I know it doesn't convert date to string, that I need and even if I use the mm/dd/yyyy date format on my form I get a function error in reference to "getTime", so really none of it works. I know the individual that helped be get this worked hard, but I just can't get to work. No reflection on him.

Comment: The key with writing code of any kind is to work incrementally. You need to test each step of the way, so when you run into an issue you can ask a specific question about that specific issue.  Since you are getting an error in reference to getTime(), I'll focus on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention in your comment you get a reference error calling getTime().

It's likely that the value of "oldDate" you are getting is not a Date object, and therefore has no getTime() function. You'll need to convert it to a Date object if you want to use getTime.  You could try

```
  var oldDate = new Date(values[i][1]);
```

which will work if the value is a a date string that Javascript understands. However if the date value is something a user is entering by hand, this will never be reliable due to typing mistakes.

I suggest putting

```
Logger.log(values[i][1]);
```

Directly above your "var oldDate..." line.  After running the script, select "Logs" from the "View" menu in the script editor to see the value you are trying to handle as a date.

That should help you figure out what is going on with your dates. Once you are sure about the date math part, move on to the writing to sheet, then finally focus on formatting the date as needed.

To deal with deleting the rows you have moved, try something like this:

```
...existing code here...

var rows_to_keep = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {

   ... existing code here ...

   if(values[i][14] == 1.0 && Math.abs(diffInDays) >= 7){
      sheet2.appendRow(values[i]);
   }else{
     //did not match
     rows_to_keep.push(values[i]);
   }
}//end of for loop

sheet1.clear();
sheet1.getRange(1,1,rows_to_keep.length,rows_to_keep[0].length).setValues(rows_to_keep);
```

A much simpler but potentially more resource-intensive/slower approach would be to delete each row as you append them, that would look like this:

```
   ...existing code here...
   if(values[i][14] == 1.0 && Math.abs(diffInDays) >= 7){
      sheet2.appendRow(values[i]);
      sheet1.deleteRow((i+1));  //+1 because Sheets starts counting at 1, while Arrays start at 0.
   }
```

For alternatives to clear(), see sheet related functions here:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet

Comment: OK, there is progress here and THANKS...I can get the effected rows to COPY but only if I run the script from editor and not onOpen of the production / Master sheet. On each run it does in fact re-copy each time I run it.....so, running manually is OK, as I can find a way to create a menu item for is somehow and make it work. Next before date formatting change is pursued, how can I MOVE or copy/delete?

Comment: Well, the logger showed the date format being "Tues Nov 5" so on my source sheet I changed my format back to "Tues, Nov 5" and the COPY still worked so it would appear converting to string is not needed. Granted, when it appends to Archive sheet it is in mm/dd/yyyy format, but I don't care about that. Still trying to figure out how to copy and delete vs. just copy.

Comment: I have noticed in testing that no matter what the date is, 7 days old or 1 day old, as long as column O is "100%" it is still copying. So, the date comparison is not working and I haven't a clue what to change. Sorry for so many responses.

Comment: I took the "+30" completely out of the IF statement and the ">=7" seem to fix the date comparison issue.

Comment: Glad you are making headway.   There is no built in concept of Moving a row from one sheet to another, so you'll have to do this manually by deleting the rows you have moved. The approach I suggest is appending rows you are not moving to a new array, then clear the original sheet, and write the new array too it, effectively "deleting" the old rows.  I'll add some example code for this step to my answer.

Comment: Cameron, thank you very much. While this does accomplish the copy and subsequent delete it also, for whatever reason, leaves my source sheet stripped of all conditional formatting. If I switch to use the simpler, more intense, method it doesn't remove my formatting, copies all the right rows, but only deletes from the source the first row copied. Sorry to be such a pain.

Comment: the clear() method does indeed clear formatting as well as the content. You can use clearContent() to eliminate only the content and leave any formatting in place.   However, if you are only ever moving a few rows at a time you probably won't have a problem with the deleteRow() approach. If you are moving hundreds of rows at a time then the clear/replace approach will become necessary.  There are trade offs to each approach, but both work.

Comment: Cameron, thanks AGAIN. Since I am only moving at most 20 rows 1 time per day that simpler will work. Can you offer any insight as to why that method copies every thing it should but only deletes from source the very first line?

Comment: Not sure why that would be happening, but I would zero in on my (i+1) statement, try using Logger.log(i); and Logger.log((i+1)); to make sure the value being passed to deleteRow() makes sense.

Comment: Cameron, thanks for all you guidance. I was able to go back to the more involved function and change the clear to.....sheet1.clear({contentsOnly: true});......and formatting stays, all rows meeting both criteria get moved. Thanks so much